# Ember.js What is the difference between the setupController and declaring a <Name>Controller

Tags: ember.js

I see many confusing examples in Ember.js official tutorials.

One example which I really don't like is:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('title', "Hello world!");
    }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    appName: 'My First Example'
});
```

Now as I understand it I could have written it like that instead:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    appName: 'My First Example',
    title: 'Hello world!'
});
```

And removing the `setupController` from route.

What is the purpose/benefit of using `setupController`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`setupController` is primarily for setting up some controller context dynamically. In your example, if the title is always gonna be "Hello world!" it's fine to set it in class declaration.

By default, `setupController` will set the `model` property of `controller` to the value returned from `model` hook of the route.

You could also you it to, for example, set the model of another controller, or set some initial controller state that depends on the model.

For example, suppose you have the following:

```
// Model
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  autoEdit: DS.attr('string')
});

// Controller
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isEditing: null,
  toggleEdit: function() { this.toggleProperty('isEditing'); }
});
```

Template:

```
<a href="#" {{action 'toggleEdit'}}>Toggle edit mode</a>

{{#if isEditing}}
  {{input type="text" value=title placeholder="Title"}}
  {{textarea type="text" value=text placeholder="Text"}}
{{else}}
  <h1>{{title}}<h1>
  <article>{{text}}</article>
{{/if}}
```

And then, you decide that it would be nice to turn editing mode on by default for posts with `autoEdit` equal to `true`. You'll probably want to do that in the route (since the controller, when instantiated, knows nothing about the model):

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    if (model.get('autoEdit')) {
      controller.set('isEditing', true);
    }
  }
});
```

So basically, it's for "initializing" the controller (setting model and default state).

Comment: I don't quite understand why dynamic context cannot be handled in class declared controller, can you give me and example.

Comment: Because when controller is instantiated, there is no model, initially, so you can't set some default state properly if it depends on the model attributes.

Comment: Still I can set model hooks in the route, I still don't understand. Route is rendering model to controller why does it matter if I change it from `setupController` or from the controller class

Comment: Actually, it's `setupController` which sets the model that the **model hook** returned to the controller (`setupController` does that by default, but of course you're free to change that). `setupController` is good if your controller has some initial state that depends on the model.

Comment: I'd be happy to see an example, it is hard for me to understand i'm new to Ember.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer on what `setupController` can be used for.

Comment: This is a nice example but please look at http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/marking-a-model-as-complete-incomplete/ there is an example there to editing property on existing model without using setupController

Comment: Please note that `isEditing` is not in the **model** (it does not need to be persisted), it's on the controller. `isEditing` simply holds some state of the current **controller**, i.e. whether the editing mode is on or off. The example you're linking to goes just by changing some **model** property, and of course there's no controller state involved.

Comment: would you use setupController for initing a Peer.js connection, or inside the init event in the controller?

Comment: A simple, explicit explanation of what the setupController does: "So basically, it's for "initializing" the controller (setting model and default state)." I wish most official documentation was as straightforward as this.